# Send image in transactional emails using var

Tags: email, transactional-mail

I'm getting the image url in transactional emails using

```
<tr><td>Url : </td><td>{{var image_url}}</td></tr>
```

But I'm not able to show image in the email when I'm using it as

```
<tr><td>Image: </td><td><img src="{{var image_url}}"/></td></tr>
```

Image format mentioned above is not correct for emails? It shows nothing against Image in email.

Comment: `image_url` is different from `img_url`

Comment: @Marius: Sorry , it was a type. Updated. Now I see image there but it's hidden by default and on clicking on "Display image below" it appears.

Comment: this is because the mail client. images can be used to track different things like if the e-mail was opened and my whom. Most e-mail clients (outlook, thunderbird, gmail) don't display images unless you tell them to do so.  The good news is that your code works. There is nothing more you can do.

Answer (score 2):

`{{var img_url}}` is correct and you are using `{{var image_url}}`

so may be you made typo mistake to call in your file

Please double check with this.

hope this will work for you.